# Out-of-process COM server

Tags: c#, com

I have a 64-bit process and I have a 32-bit DLL. I hosted the DLL in an out-of-process COM Server; the COM server is an executable application (i.e. a surrogate process). The problem is that whenever my 64-bit process exits abruptly, the server cannot determine that there are no more references to the object and exit?

Any help!

Comment: Stop your 64-bit process from exiting abruptly.  (or did you really mean when it *exists* abruptly?)

Comment: Yes i mean when it exists abruptly.

Comment: [**Exists**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exists), or [**Exits**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Exits)??

Comment: Exits; that is, when it is shutdown suddenly for some "crashing" reason.

Comment: Maybe you should add some kind of heartbeat to it, to check if the server is alive? That can be implemented in many ways like with messages.

Comment: Wrap your DLL in a layer within the COM server.  The com server itself can make calls to the dll.  Then expose its methods somehow (web service?) for your 64-bit process.

Comment: Windows will terminate orphaned out-of-process COM servers.  It takes a while, wait at least 10 minutes.  Mentioned in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171414).

Comment: @HansPassant: This will only happen if there're no COM methods being running in the server. If the client calls some method that runs for a year in the server and the client then crashes then the server will run the method for a year.

Comment: @hiddenUser, are you using DLLHost.exe for your server?

Comment: No i'm just using a standalone executable of my own.

Comment: @HansPassant Your link "this KB article" no longer works

Answer (score 1):

Have your 64-bit process create a named [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266(v=vs.85).aspx).  Have your 32-bit COM server watch that mutex, and when invalidated/closed (i.e.-due to crash), just shutdown/stop/terminate.

If you need a solution that supports several different processes, then require each process to call some type of initialize function (to your COM server) that passes in some shared handle (a mutex or otherwise) and your COM server can add it to a list.  When all handles are invalid or closed, shutdown.

You could also use a file -- 64-bit process locks a byte in a file using LockFile (or exclusive open file/etc), COM server tries to lock the file every few seconds, if it can, shutdown.

The point being, use any handle or method that will close/invalidate when a process crashes, that way the other process can detect it.  If you don't want an extra handle around, just use a handle to the process itself.  The named mutex is probably easiest to implement though, no extra functions or passing of handles required.